# Why does my subdomain structure disable javascript?

Tags: javascript, subdomain

I have a site that can be accessed two ways:

http://austin.101mobility.com/
http://101mobility.com/austin/

You will notice that the one with the subdomain structure disables the slideshow in the upper right - the one with the folder structure works correctly. Why is this?

Everything is the same as they both point to the same location. My goal however, is to 301 redirect the folder version to the subdomain version - but I can't until the slideshow is fixed.

I feel like I'm missing something really simple. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a slideshow with either.

Comment: 1) I don't see any slideshow anywhere. 2) You have a shitload of JS errors on that page (either domain), from both Google (maps?) and you own site.

Comment: It takes a second to fully load on the folder version of the domain - it's in the container where the black and white picture is above the google map

Comment: wow - thanks for pointing that out about the errors - not sure what I did wrong

Comment: I fixed the js errors with my stuff - but the google map errors are apparently a widespread issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43173

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Hot Link protection switched on for your main domain & are your javascript libraries residing there?

Comment: Not that I know of - I've never had these issues before.